# Excel Scroll Bar User Form won't Continuously Update when Dragged

Tags: excel, vba, slider, scrollbar, scrollbars

I am designing a spreadsheet that will utilise a user form with a scroll bar on it. I need to scroll bar to update the cell specified in real time as I drag the bar using the mouse, at present it only adjusts the value In the cell when I release the mouse.

I initially wanted to use a slider but from research it appears that these can't be used in a userform.

Does anyone know any VBA code or anything that will make the scroll bar continuously update as I drag the bar using the mouse?

Comment: Have you tried the SpinButton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the scroll bar on a userform and you want the update to be while dragging you need your code to be in the scroll bar's *scroll* event handler. The behavior that you descried happens with the scroll bar's *change* event handler. To see the difference, create a new userform with a scroll bar as the only control on it. In it's code module enter the following two event-handlers. When you run it you should see B1 but not A1 updating smoothly:

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    Range("A1").Value = ScrollBar1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub ScrollBar1_Scroll()
    Range("B1").Value = ScrollBar1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much.

That was easier than I thought, I feel a bit of a fool for taking 2 hours and failing to work it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome. Note that you don't have to choose - there might be reasons to include code in both event handlers. If changing the cell value triggers a large amount of spreadsheet calculations then scrolling might be sluggish. If so, you can do something like set Application.Calculation to manual in the scroll event and then have a 1-line change event handler that sets it back to automatic.